# How can I merge two data frames and extract the unique combinations of columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two data frames. The first one which is the reference df and looks like this :

| var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | e |
| b | z |
| c | f |
| d | h |

and the second one that is my universe:

| sym1 | sym2 |
| --- | --- |
| e | a |
| b | f |
| b | z |
| f | c |
| n | s |
| n | k |
| k | l |

I want to merge them and take only the unique combinations that exist in reference dataframe from all the possible pair in the universe.

Ideally I want the reported data frame to look like this :

| var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | e |
| b | z |
| c | f |
| NA | NA |

```
library(tidyverse)
var1 = c("a","b","c","d")
var2 = c("e","z","f","h")
ref = tibble(var1,var2);ref
sym1 = c("e","b","b","f","n","n","k")
sym2 = c("a","f","z","c","s","k","l")
univ = tibble(sym1,sym2);univ
```

How can I do this in R using dplyr ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base R:

```r
s <- apply(univ, 1, \(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = " "))
r <- paste(ref$var1, ref$var2)
univ[match(r, s), ]
```

```r
  sym1  sym2 
1 e     a    
2 b     z    
3 f     c    
4 NA    NA
```

---

In a single tidyverse-friendly pipe:

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
univ %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(s = str_c(sort(c_across(everything())), collapse = "")) %>% 
  pull(s) %>% 
  match(str_c(ref$var1, ref$var2), .) %>% 
  univ[., ]
```

Comment: dplyr version of your solution ?

Comment: check edit. Not as compact

Answer (score 2):

A base R one-liner

```
ref[is.na(do.call(match, lapply(list(unname(ref), unname(univ)), apply, 1, sort, simplify = FALSE))), ] <- NA
```

gives

```
> ref
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  var1  var2
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     e
2 b     z
3 c     f
4 NA    NA
```